# Send event only to clients that are in a combination of rooms with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Suppose I have a set of rooms of different sports ("football", "basketball", "tennis" ...) and a set of rooms of cities ("paris", "london", "berlin" ...) in a Node.js app with Socket.IO

Is it possible to send and event only to those from London interested in football?
Something like:

```
io.sockets.in('london').in('football').emit('event_name', data);
```

Or is it bad design?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in many ways

- You can have rooms and you want to listen to `football` event emitted

  `io.sockets.in('london').emit('football',/* data */)`
- namespaces if your application uses routes like `/london` or `/london/football`

  you can do this `io.of('/london').in('football').emit('update',/* data */` saying that in route `/london` in room `football` emit an `update` event. its slightly faster in my opinion since it doesn't group many users in one room but uses namespaces to address emit events.
- room per by city and interest.

  `io.sockets.in('london:football')` this is one room for a particular city and sport. 
  Everyone in this room gets the update about the football sport.

Comment: The first option generates a lot of unnecessary traffic, which is what I'm trying to avoid with rooms.

The second one, I'm not sure if I can use it. As far as I know, each client can only be in one namespace at the same time, right?

The third option is something I already thought of, and probably will do if I can't find a better solution, but in my case I have to do a lot of combinations. Is it expensive maintaining a lot of rooms in the application?

Thanks.